# using jquery to only send json data and not expect anything back

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

**The scenario:**

Sending search criteria to the server using json / Ajax in jquery .. the ajax call should simply end there and not expect anything back (e.g. Simply post the Json data and stop ) ..

**What is happening:**

The data is being sent, but the returned data is also being received by the ajax call :

The code:

```
public ActionResult GetBasicSearchResults(BasicSearchCriteriaInfo basicSearchCriteria)
{
    List<BasicSearchResult> results = _client.GetBasicSearchResult(basicSearchCriteria).ToList();

    return View("BasicSearchResult",results);
}
```

The Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(basicSearchCriteria),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

The `ActionResult` should render a new View based on the Received data but is sending the data back to the Ajax method. Kindly guide for possible approach.

The main aim is to only send the Data as JSON to the server and nothing else.

Comment: As I understand it, you require only to "touch/ping" the uri with some data. This can be approached both server-side and client-side. The server could close the request on entry. The client can force a timeout ( `timeout: 1,` in the ajax call object parameter )

Comment: @Jai probably because he needs to do this from a browser, limiting available methods to either xhr or inserting nodes that force http requests (img, iframe, etc)

Comment: @Khez .. Only wish to send simple data in Json format to the MVC3 controller .. if there is any other way then please inform .

Comment: @Khez Thank you for the suggestion .. have set 'timeout: 1'  in Ajax call but not working .. still the data is received by the Ajax method.

Comment: @AbdulAli The way requests work, is by "sending" some data to a server and "getting" something back. One way or another, you will get something back, be it an error, a timeout, something. Even the other methods mentioned above, will all still get something back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions ..  Have used the following approach to solving the issue..

When the data is received by the server, it processes it and saves it in **TempData** variable and send a true boolean as JSON back to the ajax call.

The Ajax call (upon receiving a true) then requests a new Action Method (using window.location) . That action method then uses the **TempData** variable to get the object and send to a Strongly Typed view for appropriate processing ..

Thanks again :)